# Repeated methods for models

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I wrote a handful of models and noticed I have repeated methods - methods which are used across all or majority of models.

What would be the best approach to porting them to another file and adding to model as required?

traits?

Comment: Go for Traits or extend Model by your methods. For an example:
`class CustomModel extends Model {}  and class Post extends CustomModel` Reference : https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/how-to-override-base-model-some-methods-in-laravel-51

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**IMHO** create an abstract class `DomainModel`, extend this class with `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` and finally use these traits inside `MyModel`

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model

abstract class DomainModel extends Model
{
    use ModelMethods1, ModelMethods2

}
```

And then extend `DomainModel` in your model classe

```
class User extends DomainModel
{

}
```

This gives you flexibility.

1. Extending your `Model Classes` from either
   `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` or `DomainModel`.
2. You can use your trait independantly in any `Model Class`

I've used this approach in a large scale project and it worked really well.

Comment: Thanks. Interesting approach, so the abstract acts as grouping for various traits? Otherwise you could just use trait directly in models? Why to use abstract?

Comment: Because we are using `DomainModel` as a proxy class only, We don't want anyone to instantiate it.

Comment: Yes, but why to use it at all? As you can use `use Model1, Mode2;` straight in parent model, what abstracting solves?

Comment: e.g you have two or three traits, you'll be using in each model, by this way your code is more organized and you can group the trait methods however you want.